# MS Office programs cause BSOD (INVALID DATA ACCESS TRAP)

Tags: microsoft-office, bsod, windows-11

Recently upgraded to Windows 11 and any time we run a Microsoft Office application (word, outlook, etc.) PC crashes and we get blue screen with INVALID DATA ACCESS TRAP listed under the stop code.

Same result whether we are using latest Office 365 apps or Office 2010 apps.

Nothing else seems to crash the PC.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: If it only happens with Office, then maybe a full uninstall/reinstall or repair of Office might fix? That stop code is usually related to a busted windows 11 upgrade though, so you may be better off just using the "Reset this PC" option to repair windows.

Comment: Post the analysis log from WinDBG

Answer (score 0):

You can start the application and Windows in the safe mode of the Office program and the safe mode of Windows, respectively, to troubleshoot the problem of Windows or Office. You can also uninstall Reinstall Office.Having both Office365 and Office 2010 installed on one device can also cause problems.